# Capacitance of spherical capacitor when inner sphere is earthed

Tags: electrostatics, charge, capacitance, conductors

Consider the following derivation:
(Source: http://www.ncert.nic.in/html/learning_basket/electricity/electricity/electrostatics/inner_sphere.htm)

[image]

If a charge of $+Q$ coulombs is given to the outer sphere $A$, it will distribute itself over both its inner and outer surfaces. Some charge $Q_2$ coulomb will remain on the outer surface of $A$ because it is surrounded by earth all around. Also some charge $+Q1$ coulombs will shift to its inner side because there is an earthed sphere $B$ inside $A$. 
$$ Q =  Q_1 + Q_2$$

The inner charge $+Q_1$ coulomb on $A$ induces $-Q_1$ coulomb on $B$ but the other induce charge of  $+Q_1$ coulomb goes to the earth.

Now, there are two capacitors connected in parallel.

i)  One capacitor consists of the inner surface of A and the outer surface of B.

ii) Second capacitor consists of outer surface of B and earth.

My question is, why are those capacitors considered to be in parallel?
Is the statement even correct, or is there any other reason for the capacitances to be added in that way?

Comment: If you say that Earth is at zero potential  and the shell b at some non zero potential Vb then you can see at one capacitor  is between 0 and Vb and other between Vb and zero so the potential diiference between them is same ..... This implies parallel arrangement

Comment: My goodness, that is one horrible looking picture.